# Why does open("url") sometimes return File sometimes StringIO?

Tags: ruby, file

I have two CSV files stored on S3. When I `open` one of them, a `File` is returned. When I `open` the other one, a `StringIO` is returned.

```
fn1 #=> "http://SOMEWHERE.s3.amazonaws.com/setup_data/d1/file1.csv" 
open(fn1) #=> #<File:/var/folders/sm/k7kyd0ns4k9bhfy7yqpjl2mh0000gn/T/open-uri20140814-26070-11cyjn1> 

fn2 #=> "http://SOMEWHERE.s3.amazonaws.com/setup_data/d2/d3/file2.csv" 
open(fn2) #=> #<StringIO:0x007f9718670ff0>
```

Why? Is there any way to open them with a consistent data type?

I need to pass the same data type `String` into `CSV.read(open(file_url))`, which doesn't work if sometimes it's getting a `File` and sometimes a `StringIO`.

They were created via different ruby scripts (they contain very different data).

On my Mac, they both appear to be ordinary text CSV files, and they were uplaoded via the AWS console, and have identical permissions and identical meta data (content-type: application/octet-stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CSV::read`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read) expects a *file path* as it’s argument, not an already opened IO object. It will then open the file and read the contents. Your code works for the Tempfile case because Ruby calls `to_path` behind the scenes on anything passed to `File::open`, and `File`s respond to this method. What happens is CSV opens *another* IO on the same file.

Rather than use `CSV::read`, you could create a new CSV object and call `read` on that (the instance method, not the class method). `CSV:new` handles IO objects correctly:

```
CSV.new(open(file_url)).read
```

Comment: great explanation and answer, thank you. tested it on the same two file urls and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

This is by design.  A tempfile is created if the size of the object is greater than 10240 bytes.  From the [source](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_9_3/lib/open-uri.rb):

```
StringMax = 10240
def <<(str)
  @io << str
  @size += str.length
  if StringIO === @io && StringMax < @size
    require 'tempfile'
    io = Tempfile.new('open-uri')
    io.binmode
    Meta.init io, @io if Meta === @io
    io << @io.string
    @io = io
  end
end
```

If you need a `StringIO` object, you could use [`fastercsv`](https://rubygems.org/gems/fastercsv).

Comment: "Is there any way to open them with a consistent data type?" I'm currently using CSV.read(open(file_url)) which, by your explanation, works if the file is big and fails if the file is small.